# Wordpress how to change Page title based on My post title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want that wordpress should display title from selected post and selected page.I am using buisness news theme. Is their any setting available or I need to change in code I am new to wordpress. I found title code in header.php

```
<title><?php
    //Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
    global $page, $paged;   
    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );
    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) echo " | $site_description";
    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'business-news' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
?></title>
```

But when I select particulate post it shows only site name in title. Where  I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<title>
    <?php single_post_title(); ?>
</title>
```

Comment: this way to every where manage display valid title. like.404 and search page.

Answer (score 0):

manage using   [add_filter wp_title() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

> **If u want change using like this  in function.php**

```
 function theme_name_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    global $page, $paged;

    // Add the blog name
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title .= " $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title .= " $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_name_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use simply :

```
 <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

For more help go to [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)